# Google GeofenceDetection example crashing

Tags: android, crash, android-geofence

I am trying to run the code ([GeofenceDetection.zip](http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html)) at:

The app keeps crashing in the emulator and also a real phone (Galaxy S3).

All I am doing is - downloading the code, adding google play services as Library and then building it with Android 4.4.2.

[image]

**Updating** with LogCat:
[image]

Comment: Dont see anything in the logcat (here it is: http://postimg.org/image/3v7whli5h/), just hangs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably missing line `<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />` in your project manifest file.

Comment: Yes that was it - thank you. Confused why the sample code did not already have it.

Comment: user1406716 - are you able to see notifications of entry exit? is the example functionally working for you;